# How to test Huawei HMS Ads?. Why we need to release application in App Gallery for testing of formal Slot ID's?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am not able to test an application with formal slot ID's. I did not found any information in documents.

Answer (score 0):

HUAWEI Ads Publisher Service provides two ways of testing your app:

1. Use a test ad unit ID

By loading a test ad using a dedicated test ad unit ID, you can prevent invalid ad clicks during the test. The test ad unit ID is only used for function commissioning.

2. Add your device as a test device and use the formal ad unit ID which you applied for.
   On HUAWEI Ads Publisher Service Console, you need to add your device to the test device list before you can use a formal ad unit ID. The procedure is as in following link:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/monetize/release-0000001050961874#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050961874__section5925134110387

Why we use test ads during testing?
During development and testing, use test ads to avoid invalid clicks and impressions. Invalid activities that can result in an increase in the ad costs paid by advertisers and the revenue earned by publishers.
Please refer the below link for prevent the invalid activities:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/monetize/policy-0000001051321913#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001051321913__section103081334584

Answer (score 0):

Other than the above info. on Huawei Ad test. Please note, if the country is the USA, you can run a formal ad unit ID test only if your devices meet all 4 conditions as below:

> 1. The vendor Country of cell phone not USA.
> 2. The SIM Country not USA.
> 3. The locale County that user set not USA.
> 4. The network IP address not USA.

If your device does not meet any of the above 4 conditions, you cannot run formal Ad unit ID test but you can still run testID ad test. Also, you can try to use Huawei cloud debugging system and choose another region's device to test your formal Ad unit ID. As to how to apply and use Huawei Cloud Devices, please refer to [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-introduction-0000001057034023)